# What type is the application file in a call to COMAdminCatalog.InstallApplication

Tags: com+

Has anyone used COMAdminCatalog.InstallApplication to successfully install an application into COM+?  If so what type of file do you need to pass as the bstrApplicationFile parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An .msi installer.  ExportApplication is the opposite (it creates an .msi installer from an existing application)